# Unhandled exception: 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the below mentioned exception while i am trying to add a rule to a Radiobutton List by calling `rules()` method.

**Unhandled exception at line 3747, column 3 in http://localhost:XXXXX/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'jQuery223064526755237397352' of undefined or null reference**

I have used the below code:

```
$('#' +RadioButton_ID).each(function () {                    
                        FieldRequired($(this), true);                    
                }
}
function FieldRequired(field, boolean) {
    if (boolean == true) {
        field.rules("add",
            {
                required: true,
                messages:
                {
                    required: errorMessage_Required
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: `} function FieldRequired(field, boolean) {` is not valid.

Comment: Hi, Alon, Please don't take braces as a reason for failure as I have edited the code before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Two things from just looking at it.

Your each is missing a closing bracket ")".

You are iterating over an id with each. Ids should be unique in your project.

Edit:
Depending on what you want you might want to use something else here than $(this).
If you really have multiple elements you want to iterate over with each, maybe try this:

```
xyz.each(function (index, element) {
    FieldRequired(element, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! No, I do have only one Radio Button List.

Comment: Then maybe using `FieldRequired(document.getElementById('#'+ RadioButton_ID), true)` is what you are looking for.

If you just want to make it required, did you try `$('#' + RadioButton_ID).prop('required',true);`?

But I just assumed this by the way your stuff is named.